# Mocking the C++ Standard Library

Tags: c++, unit-testing, mocking, standard-library, std

I'm unit testing a class in C++ and some of the public methods call private ones.  I know convention is to test the public interface, but the classes' functionality depends on how these private methods in turn invoke other classes and their methods.  This is similar to the public interface in the sense that no matter what happens to the private function it will still conform to the API.

I've been able to mock the classes invoked in the private function for the most part to test the API, but in a few cases I've run into places where the standard library is referenced and haven't managed to mock it.  Are there any tricks to mocking standard library classes etc?  Or should I skip them?

--
Also I'm not able to either change the source or use mocking libraries.

Comment: std smells of elderberries...

Comment: It's not very common to need to mock STL. Why do you think you need to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really wish to mock the standard library then the easiest (possibly only) approach is to instrument your code correctly. That is, instead of using the headers and `std` namespace directly you'll have to use an intermediary name.

So invent a namespace, call it `mstd`. In your mocked mode this will be your mock namespace. In non-mock mode this will simply be an alias to `std`.

For header files you'll have to avoid including the standard headers directly, but use a mocking layer. So instead of including `<map>` you could include `<mk-map>`. This header file will then decide between the standard library and your version. Perhaps like this:

```
#ifdef MOCK_MODE
    #include "mock/map.hpp"
#else
    #include <map>
#endif
```

You could alternately give a different include path to your compiler, one that comes before the standard libraries. However, since you have to alias the namespace anyway you'll still have to modify all of your code -- thus it's just as easy to include these special headers.

This is about the only way I can see this working.  Note that using LD_PRELOAD or any library technique will not work: the C++ standard library is made up of a lot of template classes and inline functions. You need to replace them right at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do some whitebox testing of a class's private methods, maybe your compiler will let you bypass the access control?  GCC at least allows `-fno-access-control`, which I have used with great success for both whitebox unit tests and introspection into data structures, i.e. hash collisions in `unordered_{set,map}`.

Skipping access control also lets you muck directly with the member variables in between other calls, if you *really* want to be devious.

Comment: If you're whitebox testing (and _only_ in this case) then all bets are off. I just `#define private public` in my test code, although it makes my skin crawl. Likewise, although you should never, ever do it in mainline code, you can inject things into the `std` namespace. I found myself having to do this to whitebox a pseudorandom number generator so I could get repeatable seeds.

Answer (score 1):

For such purposes, I would recommend you [Typemock Isolator++](https://www.typemock.com/docs?book=Ipp&page=Documentation%2Fintroduction.htm) API, that allows to mock global methods without any redefinings.
Look, how easy it is:

```
FAKE_GLOBAL(fopen);
WHEN_CALLED(fopen(0,0)).Return(_anotherFile);
```

And you don't even need to change the source code.

Answer (score -1):

Is it really necessary to make mockups of the standard library? Sure, it's possible that the standard library functions have bugs, but your mockups are probably more likely to have bugs than they are.

I would say to just use them as they are. If you track down a test failure to the standard library, then you've found a standard library bug. And, at least for the near term, you will probably have to find a way to work around such bugs.

Comment: I'd say the potentially useful thing is not simulating std library bugs, but reactions to possible run-time scenarios such as full filesystems, memory exhaustion, file-name permissioning problems & race conditions etc....  (Anyway, this is more by way of comment than potential answer).

Comment: If you want to mock system calls, you should be using `LD_PRELOAD` with the underlying glibc calls, not anything at the libstdc++ level.  C++ is the wrong level of abstraction to deal with the operating system.